# SE summary site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, summary

Is there (or will there be) a site/place that shows a summary of all my accounts of all SE sites? In the morning I'd like to see if there were any comments, messages, answers etc. I'd have to read, but since we're now active on dozens of different sites this becomes a rather big task.

It would also be nice if you could do things like update your profile at a single place (although I can imagine people placing a 'professional' profile on SO but a more 'personal' one on SE Cats & Dogs, so this shouldn't be the default...)

Comment: Check out http://stackapps.com -- there may be something built using the API that does this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be something there now. Maybe I'll start one someday. The `/users/{id}/associated` API function would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

There is now both the Inbox and your activity in your network profile.